# File I/O function for C

Tags: c, file-io

```
char *loadTextFile(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fileh;
    char *text = 0;
    long filelength;
    if((fileh=fopen(filename,"rb"))== 0)
        printf("loadTextFile() - could not open file");
    else
    {
        fseek(fileh, 0, SEEK_END);
        filelength = ftell(fileh);
        rewind(fileh);
        text=(char *) smartmalloc((int)filelength + 1);
        fread(text,(int)filelength, 1, fileh);
        fclose(fileh);
        text[filelength]=0;
    }
    printf(text);
    return(text);
}
```

This function only returns partial data of a txt file. It is also inconsistent...soemtimes gives me 100 characters of the file some times 20. I don't see anything wrong with it. Thought I might get another pair of eyes on it. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to formulate your question as a question. It helps if you make it clear what you expect as an answer, perhaps having an interrogation mark somewhere.

Comment: I see a few things wrong with it. For example, there is no standard `C` function called `smartmalloc`. I'll post a revised version.

Comment: this is a cgi-html library function

Comment: @Tommy: Bad library ... bad, bad, bad library.

Comment: Is your text file encoding consistent?

Comment: You should be checking the return from `fread()`, see if it matches the length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a *slightly* better version of your code. You need more error checking with the IO function calls. Also, there is the annoying `long` to `size_t` implicit conversions which I would recommend dealing with properly in production code.

```
char* loadTextFile(const char *filename) {
    char *text;
    long length;

    FILE *fileh = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if ( !fileh ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    fseek(fileh, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(fileh);
    rewind(fileh);

    text = malloc(length + 1);

    if ( !text ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    fread(text, 1, length, fileh);
    text[length] = 0;

    fclose(fileh);

    return text;
}
```

Note that, [John R. Strohm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329729/file-i-o-function-for-c/1329779#1329779) is right: If your assessment of what has been read is based on what `printf` prints, then you are likely being misled by embedded `nul`s.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate that. Going to see if I can figure out the bad function first.

Comment: Looks like I was mislead with printf and the debugger.
When I displayed the returned data at it's final destination (web page) it displays all. Not sure why I don't see it all in the debugger.

Comment: @Tommy because any embedded `nul`s tell both `printf` and the debugger where the end of a string is.

Answer (score 4):

Obvious things to check:

What did ftell(fileh) give you?

Can there be embedded NUL characters in the file?  That would cause printf(text) to stop prematurely.

Comment: looks like the right amount of chars 2705
Yes, there probably are, but I am thrown off because i get different places where it terminates, it's not consistent.

Comment: This is an indicator that your file has NULLs in it. Substitute the last printf for

fwrite(text, 1, length, stdout);

and tell the result

Answer (score 3):

**`fread` is not guaranteed to return as many characters as you ask for**.  You need to check its return value and use it in a loop.

Example loop (not tested):

```
char *p = text;
do {
    size_t n = fread(p,1,(size_t)filelength, fileh);
    if (n == 0) {
       *p = '\0';
       break;
    }
    filelength -= n;
    p += n;
} while (filelength > 0);
```

The test for `n==0` catches the case where some other process truncates the file as you are trying to read it.